# "At the dawn of" or "Since the dawn of"

Tags: word-choice

I have this sentence:

> ____ the dawn of television history, there were two distinct paths of technology experimented with by researchers.

What should I choose for the dash? **At** or **Since**. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

"At", if you are sticking with "there were", suggesting a past event that has occurred and finished [the divergence of paths].

"Since" would be used if you said "there have been", suggesting that there was a divergence that is still very much ongoing.

It's whether you see the divergence as a singular act at a singular-ish point in time, or as an ongoing divergence, diverging more and more, even as you write this.

Comment: So it should be **at** in my sentence right?